Laravel abstract model implementation
Implement abstract base model for later realizations:
abstract class AbstractNode extends Model
{
    use HasFactory;

    protected static function boot(): void
    {
        static::creating(static function (self $model) {
            //
        });
        static::deleting(static function (self $model) {
            //
        });
    }

    abstract public function getTitle(): string;
    abstract public function getAllowedChildren(): ?array;
}

then instantiate this base model:
class Region extends AbstractNode
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'name', // Region name
    ];

    public function getTitle(): string
    {
        return 'Region';
    }

    public function getAllowedChildren(): ?array
    {
        return null;
    }
}

Usage of Region class as $region = new Region(); ends with fatal error:
Undefined array key "App\Models\Region"

When I code Region as extends Model, not AbstractNode - everything ok.
Is it possible to use abstract model classes?

This question has been answered. But in general, it is not a good idea to create an abstract model class this way. For common behaviors, you can extract those to a trait.
